# Align vertical 3 plots in 2 rows in cowplot package in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, cowplot

I would like to align vertical plot from row 1 and plot from row 2. It didn't matter how hard I try, but it did not let me align.

[image]

Any ideas?

```
library(dplyr)
library(forcats)
library(ggplot2)
library(cowplot)

city_mpg <- mpg %>%
  mutate(class = fct_lump(class, 4, other_level = "other")) %>%
  group_by(class) %>%
  summarize(
    mean_mpg = mean(cty),
    count = n()
  ) %>% mutate(
    class = fct_reorder(class, count)
  )

p1 <- ggplot(city_mpg, aes(class, count)) + 
  geom_col() + 
  ylim(0, 65) + 
  coord_flip()

p2 <- ggplot(city_mpg, aes(mean_mpg, count)) + 
  geom_point()

p3 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) +
  geom_point()

first <- plot_grid(p1, p2, align = 'h', axis = 'l',rel_widths = c(2,1))
second <- plot_grid(p3)
plot_grid(first, second,ncol = 1, align = 'v', axis = 'l',rel_heights = c(2,1))
```

Answer (score 0):

The terminology here in terms of `ggplot` would be that the *plots* align just fine - it's the *panels* that do not align.  The "panel" represents the area between the x and y axes, and the "plot" is considered the entire area taken up by the panel + the axis ticks, axis text, and axis titles.

Why is this important?  Well, `plot_grid()` aligns all *plots*, but not the *panels*.  Since `p1` has longer y axis text than the y axis text of `p3`, the area to the left of the panel in `p1` is also wider.  When you align the left side of `p1` and `p3`, it means the panel of `p3` is to the left of `p1`.

The simple fix for this is to just add a bit of a margin to `p3`.  By using `theme(plot.margin)`, we can add some room to the left of `p3` so that the area to the left of the panel in `p3` is roughly similar to that in `p1`.  The unfortunate thing is that it's not really very straightforward to do this in any other way than trial and error.  You have to add some margin and plot again to see if it was too much or too little.  In the end, the result works though.  Similarly, I added some margin to the right side of `p3` to get the right part of that panel aligned with the right side of the `p2` panel.

To fix, the code for `p3` now looks like this:

```
p3 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme(plot.margin = margin(l=44, t=0, b=0, r=6, 'pt'))
```

[image]